# nodeJS AWS S3 upload data wrong encoding

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a little app to upload a file to AWS S3, it is uploading ok, but when I download the file from S3 bucket, it is encoded, shows type:buffer etc...

if I upload the same file from the console, it shows fine.

Here the code to upload

```
const fs = require('fs');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
});

const fileName = 'su.csv';
const uploadFile = () => {
    fs.readFile(fileName, (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        const params = {
            Bucket: 'mybukk22-test', // pass your bucket name
            Key: 'su.csv', // file will be saved as testBucket/contacts.csv
            Body: JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)
        };
        s3.upload(params, function (s3Err, data) {
            if (s3Err) throw s3Err
            console.log(`File uploaded successfully at ${data.Location}`)
        });
    });
};

uploadFile();
```

Is the problem on the body? how to save the same file as on client?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to do a `JSON.stringify` on a `Buffer`, because `fs.readFile` returns you a `Buffer`. To make it work you could change your `params` to the following:

```
const params = {
    Bucket: 'mybukk22-test', // pass your bucket name
    Key: 'su.csv', // file will be saved as testBucket/contacts.csv
    Body: data
};
```

(Just pass `data` 1:1 as the `Body` of your `upload` operation)

Otherwise, if you like to stick to your solution just cast `data` to a string like this: `JSON.stringify(data.toString(), null, 2)`